# How to interact with zenity window and type some text inside it?

Tags: 18.04, bash, python, xdotool, zenity

I have python code :

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['sh', './zenity.sh'])
```

and zenity.sh file which is

```
#!/usr/bin/python

zenity --forms --title="Question" \
   --add-entry="Question" \
```

Running it opens window with field to type some text.

I want to type some text inside this zenity window using for e.g. xdotool I tried to use

```
subprocess.call(["xdotool", "type", "some text"])
```

not working

then I created another .sh

```
#!/bin/bash


xdotool search --class zenity windowfocus type 'some text'
```

also not working

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### There are two requirements for `xdotool` to work with your example:

- You should be running **X11** and not **Wayland**.
- Your window created by `zenity` must be fully loaded before the `xdotool` command is run.

#### To do this properly, you need to:

1. Load the window in the **background** ( with `&` ) like so:

   ```
   zenity --forms --title="Question" --add-entry="Question" &
   ```
2. Give some time for the window to fully load ( with `sleep` ) like so:

   ```
   sleep 1
   ```
3. Get your window ID by name like so:

   ```
   window="$(xdotool search --name 'Question')"
   ```
4. Activate your window by ID ( stored in `$window` in step 3 above ) like so:

   ```
   xdotool windowactivate "$window"
   ```
5. Type the text in the window like so:

   ```
   xdotool type 'some text'
   ```

#### So the final script will look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

zenity --forms --title="Question" --add-entry="Question" &

sleep 1

window="$(xdotool search --name 'Question')"

xdotool windowactivate "$window"

xdotool type 'some text'
```

Answer (score 5):

Change your `zenity.sh` file with:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

zenity --forms --title="Question" \
   --add-entry="Question" \
```

To:

```
#!/bin/bash

zenity --forms --title="Question" \
   --add-entry="Question" \
```

You are not calling `zenity` within a python script. You are calling it from a bash/shell command so your shebang (first line) must be `#!/bin/bash` not `#!/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: +1 for noticing that shebang.... I missed it :)

Comment: Since OP runs `sh ./zenity.sh`, the shebang makes no difference here, Change it `#! /usr/bin/bash` and it will still be run with `sh`.